# SSRS - Get the Subscription execution time

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a query that gives me all the details about my Subscriptions in SSRS.

I join `dbo.Subscriptions` to `dbo.ExecutionLogStorage` on `ReportID`, however that gives me the last execution time for this particular report.

The same report is used with many parameters that can influence the execution time. Is there a way to connect `LogStorage` with particular instance of the Subscription?

I manage to identify what is a Subscription by looking at UserName and filtering by the SQL service account (that runs the Reporting Services) but getting the last for `ReportID` still doesn't means it is for that specific run, it only narrows it down to the last of the run of the service account for that report.

Simple part of the query I'm running:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM dbo.Subscriptions s
    LEFT JOIN dbo.ExecutionLogStorage els ON els.ReportID = s.Report_OID
```

but of course it gives me execution of each instance of the report in the subscription

Comment: How are you joining `Subscriptions` and `ExecutionLogStorage`? Share the query you are trying. I have 7 report subscriptions running on a daily basis, I can get the execution details for every subscription.

Comment: I added simple part of the query in the edit

Comment: You need to add a where clause to your query

Comment: And use which field? I need to see the last execution (in this cases all are fine I can tweak it later) to the particular subscription not just report

Comment: @Edga , I am unsure about what you want to see, a subscription is related to only one report, you will see execution details per subscription therefore execution details per report.

Comment: Not if I have multiple subscription per report. I have a report AA, and Subscriptions AA1, AA2, AA3, AA4  - if I query ExecutionlogStorage I can only see collectively 4 runs of report AA, but I want to see how long particular subscription took, for example AA3

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a where cause to your query.

```
WHERE S.Parameters != '<ParameterValues />'
```

or

```
WHERE S.Parameters = '<ParameterValues>
                          <ParameterValue>
                              <Name>(ParmeterName)</Name>
                              <Value>(Parameter Value) </Value>
                          </ParameterValue>
                      </ParameterValues>'
```

Something like the above to find any parameters added or the second where to find specific values.